# Calling curl command in Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, curl, github-api

I want to call this cURL command in my iPhone app.

```
curl --user "username:PASSWD" https://api.github.com/users/username
```

How can I execute it in objective C? I tried many methods but didn't succeed.
Please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

To invoke a comand using the shell, use the `system()` function:

```
system("curl --foo --bar");
```

However, **do not do this.** It's a hack. Use libcurl or the NSURL API for networking. You may as well use libgit2 for checking out git repositories.

Comment: It's not obsolete, so much as totally awful. You really don't want to be calling out to the shell for a networking call. Listen to H2CO3's wise words!

Comment: can you please explain it briefly? I didn't get anything.

Comment: @AKV Oh thanks. Well, I don't see any particular reason to involve another extra level of abstraction.

Comment: @Rox You don't know how to call a function or what?

Comment: I don't know about libcurl. How to use it?

Comment: @AKV Of course you can, but again, I don't see any particular reason for it. It's a bit of an over-engineering.

Comment: @H2CO3 documentation is very confusing. Can you help me to implement this in my objective c code (iPhone app)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NSTask will not work under sandbox environment (you will get "deny process-fork"). So put your application into /Applications

You can use `NSTask` for executing any system commands.

```
NSTask *task=[NSTask new];
[task setLaunchPath:@"curl --user "username:PASSWD" https://api.github.com/users/username"];
[task launch];
```